# Xmlreader - get element by name and write out childelements c# webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, webforms, xmlreader

Im trying to write out every childelement within the "fruit" rankings element. As the code is now, it goes to the first ranking element in my xml file and output the childelements within: But how do I by name go to "fruit" and write out it's childlements?

Xml

```
 <ranking name="Browers>
 <stat name="Chrome" />
 <stat name="Firefox" />
 <stat name="Safari" />
 </ranking>
<ranking name="Fruit>
 <stat name="Apple" />
 <stat name="Orange" />
 <stat name="Strawberry" />
 </ranking>
```

Codebehind

```
   XmlReader reader =       XmlReader.Create(Server.MapPath("/temp/rankings.xml"));

    while (true)
    {
        reader.ReadToFollowing("ranking");
        string name = reader.GetAttribute("name");

        if (name == "Fruit")
        {
            if (reader.ReadToDescendant("stat"))
            {
                do
                {
                    litList.Text += reader.GetAttribute("name") + "<br />";
                    litList.Text += reader.GetAttribute("percent") + "<br />";
                    litList.Text += reader.GetAttribute("absolute") + "<br />";


                } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("stat"));
            }

            break;
        }  
    }
```

Comment: What about two loops? First for rankings, second for stats?

Comment: It worked, wasen't thinking clearly.

Comment: So, if there is not a ranking called fruit then youll enter an infinite loop? this code you posted will *gasp* work for your **very** specific needs, but this is not really the way to do this. (Just saying in case someone else needs something similar they won't be copy/pasting this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done like this:

```
        if (reader.ReadToFollowing("ranking"))
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ranking: " + reader.GetAttribute("name"));
                if (reader.ReadToDescendant("stat"))
                {
                    do
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Stat: " + reader.GetAttribute("name"));
                    } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("stat"));
                }
            } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("ranking"));
        }
```

It may have some drawbacks. Instead of XmlReader you also could use XDocument: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx